# How do you pass unchecked checkbox value using Coldfusion.ajax.submitform?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I'm stumped. I have a `<cfform>` and I'm saving the form info to a database using a cfc and Coldfusion.Ajax.submitform. My form uses checkboxes. What I can't seem to figure out is how to capture if a checkbox is unchecked. I've read that if a checkbox is unchecked, it doesn't get sent with the form info. I've also read that you can use `<cfparam>` to give the checkbox a default value so that if the checkbox is unchecked, it will still have a value e.g. `<cfparam name="form.checkbox1" default="0">`. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work when I use ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: cfparam happens on the form processing page after the javascript submits the form so i'm not sure why 'it doesn't seem to work'.  what do you get when you <cfdump var = "#form#">

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are you saying the `<cfparam>` definition needs to be on the cfc as opposed to the .cfm that contains my form? Currently, I have the default settings happening on the form before the the values are sent to the cfc. I'll also check with the `<cfdump>`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be on the cfc, setting it on the form page only makes it accessible on that page.

Comment: Hey Travis. Hey Matt. Thank you so much. Yep, moved those `<cfparam>` default values over to my cfc and everything works. :)

Comment: If someone answered your question, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a proper answer so you can close this question.

Per the ColdFusion documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7faf.html

> Cfparam tests for the existence of a parameter (that is, a variable),
>   validates its data, and, if a default value is not assigned,
>   optionally provides one.

Mostly it's just used to create a default value for a variable of pretty much any scope.

As you have discovered, the cfparam tag must be used when the variable is required, in the processing page. cfquery param creates the variable in memory on the coldfusion server and is only available for the duration of the request (unless you use it to set a value to a persistent scope like session or application). It does not create form elements or javascript variables